# Использование роутера с отключенным WiFi

Tags: железо, роутер

Я чайник.
У меня есть два компьютера и принтер, которые подключаются к роутеру (D-Link DSL-G225, если это важно). Все они находятся в разных комнатах одной небольшой квартиры.

Сейчас я делаю ремонт, и у меня возникла идея:
— Можно ли как-то провести провода внутри стен, чтобы все устройства общались по проводам, без WiFi?
Если просто всех присоединить к роутеру длинными проводами, то двери не закрываются и это неудобно.

Comment: Нет никакой разницы между проводами внутри стен и снаружи стен - главное чтобы они были присоединены одним концом к устройству, другим - к роутеру

Comment: @insolor, 4  лан порта. Вопрос, как это сделать технически. Просто замуровать провода, и они будут висеть из стен? Можно ли сделать что-то вроде розеток, куда все подключаются?

Comment: Именно с помощью розеток. Есть розетки под коннектор RJ-45.

Comment: P.S. для монтажа провода в розетки нужен будет специальный инструмент, в магазине DNS он называется "Инструмент для заделки кабеля". Также рекомендую приобрести/где-то взять в пользование тестер соединения.

Comment: у меня так и сделано - по квартире разведено 4 кабеля по разным комнатам, изначально брал кабель, который гигабит держит. Сейчас понимаю, что нужно было больше ставить, пришлось на своем столе ещё один роутер поставить. Розеток под это дело вагон и тележка. Любой маломальский монтажник в курсе. Главное не поскупится на кабель. Также нормальные монтажники легко сверлят дырку в стенке и пропускают кабель, который можно спрятать в короб/плинтус.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Провода закладываются в стену 2мя способами.

1. Неглубокая штроба. Провод в полителене (черный)  заштакатуривается в этой штробе.
2. Труба жёсткая или гофра замуровывается в стену. Провод затаскивается протяжкой после ремонта

Розетки под кабель есть у многих производителей.

Без заделки чтоб закрывалась дверь сверли отверстие  за плинтусом или заводи кабель за косяком.

Comment: Спасибо! Я хочу убедиться, что правильно поняла топологию: * В центре находится роутер. От 3 его LAN-портов отходят провода, включенные в розетки RJ-45. * От каждой розетки внутри стены идет провод к устройству, и на выходе из стены кончается, опять же, розеткой RJ-45. * Каждое усторйство подключается через свою розетку к своему LAN-порту. ** Всего требуется 6 розеток RJ-45, кабель длиной в 3 пути внутри стен, дополнительные провода с коннекторами RJ-45 и, наверное, еще круглые крышки для мест, где кабель поворачивает в стене. Правильно?

Comment: из чего сделанна стена?

Comment: Дом немолодой. Несущие столбы из железобетона, а стены из материала, который в Израиле называется "тит". Насколько я понимаю, это цемент с песком и известкой.   Мастер, который делает мне ремонт, уже штробил и добавлял розетки. Осталось уговорить его научится делать розетки для интернета за добавочное вознаграждение.

Comment: также штробится, как и под розетки. насчет поворотов не понял - штроба вертикальная до розетки, а разводка по потолку...)